# How to check if datalist is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```js
var dl=document.getElementById("rptImages");                                     
var rowArray = dl.getElementsByTagName('tr');                   
if ( rowArray.length <= 0 )
{
  alert('No data in DataList');                        
}
```

but in this code I didn't get alert when no data in Datalist, I am getting error message `'getElementsByTagName' is undefined or null reference.`

Comment: `if ( rowArray.length === 0 )`

Comment: @synthet1c `rowArray.length <= 0` do the same

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your first line doesn't find the element:

```
var dl = document.getElementById("rptImages");
```

as the error effectively complains that *dl* is null.